# run terraform in azure pipeline to deploy to another tenant

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-service-principal

I use 2 Azure tenants:

tenantA for storing repository and pipeline

tenantB for deploying infrastructure, terraform (backend) state file is stored here too

so I grab repo from tenantA, connect with `az login` to tenantB and run terraform commands. Now I'd like to use Azure pipeline in tenantA to automate this process. I created service principal in tenantA connecting to tenantB. Verification succeeded, `az login --service-principal -u "spn_id" -p "spn_secret" --tenant "tenantB_id"` works too. However, when I run the pipeline from tenantA, or when I log-in with `az login` to tenantA and run terraform, I get an error:

**Error: Error building ARM Config: obtain subscription(id) from Azure CLI: parsing json result from the Azure CI: waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: Subscription 'id' not found. Check the spelling and try again.**

my TF code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
    backend "azurerm" {
      tenant_id            = tenantB_id
      subscription_id      = tenantB_subscription_id
      resource_group_name  = resource_group_name
      storage_account_name = storage_account_name
      container_name       = container_name
      key                  = key_name
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  client_id       = tenantA_service_principal_id
  client_secret   = tenantA_service_principal_secret
  tenant_id       = tenantB_id
  subscription_id = tenantB_subscription_id
}
```

note, that in tenantA I have no subscriptions, I can only log-in with `az login --allow-no-subscriptions`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

You need to do `az login`
Login with the credentials and

Set subscription  for the tenant B

```
az account set --subscription <desiredSubscriptionId>
```

[image]

You can give `az login --allow-no-subscriptions` gives tenant level access.

Since you are using a service principal to authenticate with tenantB, make sure the service principal has the necessary permissions in tenant B to access the subscription. Assign  the service principal the "Contributor" role or higher tenantB subscription.

Additionally check the  subscription ID is correct in the Terraform code.

Without subscription being correctly given you will be facing subscription errors.

```
Status=404 Code="SubscriptionNotFound" Message="The subscription 'fx0' could not be found."xx
```

[image]

With wrong tenant  you may face errors as :Error building ARM Config: please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version

In that case run the below command to set correct tenant where proper permissions like contributor are given .

```
az login --tenant TENANT_ID
```

Assin contributor role using terraform .

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope              = "/subscriptions/${var.tenantB_subscription_id}"
  role_definition_id = "/subscriptions/${var.tenantB_subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/${var.role_definition_id}"   or // azurerm_role_definition.Contributor.id
  principal_id       = var.tenantA_service_principal_id
}
```

or you can do it through Azure cli

```
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id <ServiceprincipleObjectId> --assignee-principal-type ServicePrincipal --role Reader --scope /subscriptions/subscrptionIdoFtenantB/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup --name <Idofrole>
```

[image]

Then try to run **`terraform init`** > `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`